# Unnamed parameter with commander.js (positional arguments)

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, node-commander

I am currently taking a look at [commander.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/commander.js) as I want to implement a CLI using Node.js.

Using named parameters is easy, as the example of a "pizza" program shows:

```
program
  .version('0.0.1')
  .option('-p, --peppers', 'Add peppers')
  .option('-P, --pineapple', 'Add pineapple')
  .option('-b, --bbq', 'Add bbq sauce')
  .option('-c, --cheese [type]', 'Add the specified type of cheese [marble]', 'marble')
  .parse(process.argv);
```

Now, e.g., I can call the program using:

```
$ app -p -b
```

But what about an unnamed parameter? What if I want to call it using

```
$ app italian -p -b
```

? I think this is not so very uncommon, hence providing files for the `cp` command does not require you to use named parameters as well. It's just

```
$ cp source target
```

and not:

```
$ cp -s source -t target
```

How do I achieve this using commander.js?

And, how do I tell commander.js that unnamed parameters are required? E.g., if you take a look at the `cp` command, source and target are required.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With the present version of commander, it's possible to use positional arguments. See the [docs on argument syntax](https://github.com/tj/commander.js/#specify-the-argument-syntax) for details, but using your `cp` example it would be something like:

```
program
.version('0.0.1')
.arguments('<source> <target>')
.action(function(source, target) {
    // do something with source and target
})
.parse(process.argv);
```

This program will complain if both arguments are not present, and give an appropriate warning message.

Answer (score 8):

You get all the unnamed parameters through `program.args`. Add the following line to your example

```
console.log(' args: %j', program.args);
```

When you run your app with `-p -b -c gouda arg1 arg2` you get

```
you ordered a pizza with:
- peppers
- bbq
- gouda cheese
args: ["arg1","arg2"]
```

Then you could write something like

```
copy args[0] to args[1] // just to give an idea
```

Comment: Basically, this is a fine option, but - how do I specify that the arguments are mandatory?

Comment: you could do something like `if (!program.args.length) console.log('Please use the following syntax: cp source destination')`

Comment: Yes, of course, but my question is whether commander.js has built-in support for this, including coercion and all its other nice features.

Comment: Unfortunately not, so I'm still looking for an answer, too :-/

Comment: @Golo Roden you can make the arguments mandatory by specifying them  with angled brackets -e.g. `<arg1>`, and optional by using squared brackets -e.g. `[arg2]`.

Answer (score 1):

**`program.argument('<myarg>')` + `program.namedArgs` as of 9.4.1 for positional arguments**

Tested as of commander 9.4.1 the best option for positional arguments seems to be the `.argument` function.

This method achieves the basic features you'd expect from a decent library:

- gives an error if mandatory arguments are not passed
- allows you to set defaults and do custom parsing/checks e.g. integer conversion
- give an error if there are too many positional with `program.allowExcessArguments(false)` (shame not the default)

We use `program.namedArgs` because `program.args` ignores `myParseInt` or defaults.

TODO built-in way to

- access positional arguments by their name (e.g. `program.processedArgs.arg1`) rather than by index (`program.processedArgs[0]`)

Sample usage:

positional.js

```
function myParseInt(value, dummyPrevious) {
  const parsedValue = parseInt(value, 10);
  if (isNaN(parsedValue)) {
    throw new commander.InvalidArgumentError('Not a number.');
  }
  return parsedValue;
}

const commander = require('commander');
const program = commander.program
program.option('-m --myopt <myopt>', 'doc for myopt', 'myopt-default');
program.argument('<arg1>', 'doc for arg1');
program.argument('<arg2>', 'doc for arg2');
program.argument('[arg3]', 'doc for arg3', myParseInt, 1);
program.allowExcessArguments(false);
program.parse(process.argv);
const [arg1, arg2, arg3] = program.processedArgs
const opts = program.opts()

// Use the arguments.
console.error(`arg1: ${arg1} (${typeof arg1})`);
console.error(`arg2: ${arg2} (${typeof arg2})`);
console.error(`arg3: ${arg3} (${typeof arg3})`);
console.error(`myopt: ${opts.myopt} (${typeof opts.myopt})`);
```

Sample calls:

```
$ ./positional.js 
error: missing required argument 'arg1'
$ ./positional.js a
error: missing required argument 'arg2'
$ ./positional.js a b
arg1: a (string)
arg2: b (string)
arg3: 1 (number)
myopt: myopt-default (string)
$ ./positional.js a b c
error: command-argument value 'c' is invalid for argument 'arg3'. Not a number.
$ ./positional.js a b 2
arg1: a (string)
arg2: b (string)
arg3: 2 (number)
myopt: myopt-default (string)
$ ./positional.js a b 2 c
error: too many arguments. Expected 3 arguments but got 4.
$ ./positional.js -m c a b 2
arg1: a (string)
arg2: b (string)
arg3: 2 (number)
myopt: c (string)
$ ./positional.js a b 2 -m c
arg1: a (string)
arg2: b (string)
arg3: 2 (number)
myopt: c (string)
$ ./positional.js -h
Usage: positional [options] <arg1> <arg2> [arg3]

Arguments:
  arg1                doc for arg1
  arg2                doc for arg2
  arg3                doc for arg3 (default: 1)

Options:
  -m --myopt <myopt>  doc for myopt (default: "myopt-default")
  -h, --help          display help for command
```

Comment: `program.args` has the plain text arguments. See `program.processedArgs` for the arguments after custom processing.

Comment: @shadowspawn nice, updated. Any way to make commander check if there are too many positional arguments besides manual `program.args` check?

Comment: Yes: `program.allowExcessArguments(false)`